# In iOS 7.1, UISearchBar's text and placeholder properties don't work anymore

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7

Starting from iOS **7.1**, I have not been able to read the text nor set the placeholder of UISearchBar. The text property always returns nil and the search bar is always a blank white rectangle. In iOS **7.0** and below, I had no such problems. Does 7.1 require me to treat UISearchBars differently to make `text` and `placeholder` work?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
    self.searchBar.placeholder = @"placeholder doesn't work in 7.1";
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];

    self.button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 100.0, 44.0)];
    self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.button setTitle:@"print text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(printSearchText) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.button]; 
}

- (void)printSearchText
{
    NSLog(@"print nil here: %@", self.searchBar.text);
}
```

Comment: Works for me.  I had to add [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar] to your code

Comment: forgot about the addSubview, but the problem still persists. I made sure I have no UIAppearance for UISearchBar that could screw it up

Comment: I created a blank single-view project in Xcode and pasted your code into the view controller.  The placeholder text appeared and the search bar text property had the correct string. I tested on both the iPhone simulator and my iPhone 5s running 7.1.  You may need to look at your code more closely.

Comment: yeah. I also created a blank project and everything works. I will check what specialized code caused the problem...

Comment: I don't know if you are 100% creating your views by code or mixing code & IB but I have had problems before where an IB object was being overwritten by a code created object with the result that the object on screen and the object being referred to by the code were different.

Comment: I am writing everything in code. I still can't find the problem. I checked that the address of the search bar pointer is the same from whence it was created to the time I attempt to print out the text - they are the same pointer.

Comment: I've got the same problem.  The same build works fine in iOS 7 but the placeholders are missing in 7.1.

Comment: Actually, I don't have any problems accessing the text property of the search bar -- all the search functionality works fine, just the placeholder is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not be related to your problem, but we had a similar problem caused by a category we'd defined on `UISearchBar`.  We'd added a `textField` property for some hacky reasons I won't go into.  It appears that Apple added their own internal `textField` property in iOS 7.1 and ours was interfering with it.

This is a good reason to always prefix your category method/property names.  :)

Comment: I defined a `searchBar` property in a `UISearchBar` category. Apprently iOS 7.1 added that property to the framework.