# How does a category run when its not imported in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, overriding, objective-c-category

## Question

How is it possible that a category in objective-c is affecting my program if it is not imported anywhere? Its mere existence in a file is changing the outcome of the program.

## Anecdote

My UISearchBar broke starting in iOS 7.1. A fellow StackOverflow member suggested that one of my categories may have [overridden a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22647452/1390119) introduced to UISearchBar in iOS 7.1. His suspicion was correct. I tested his theory by slowly commenting out all imports of my UISearchBar categories. After commenting out the last category, my search bar was still broken. In an act of desperation, I physically deleted my UISearchBar category files one by one. I discovered that after deleting the following file, my search bar started working again.

```
#import "UISearchBar+CustomUI.h"

@implementation UISearchBar (CustomUI)

- (UITextField*)searchField
{
    UITextField *searchField = nil;
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            searchField = (UITextField *)subview;
            break;
        }
    }
    return searchField;
}

@end
```

Yes, I know the above is fragile code, but there are unconventional design requirements that force programmers to hack.

Comment: This is why it's often not recommended to override methods with categories. Categories can even impact Apple's private API's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you have not imported the category, it is probably compiled into the binary. Check the `Compile Sources` in `Build Phases` and you should see your category there or in the `File Inspector` under `Target Membership`. Effectively the category will be loaded in runtime and so the methods will be overridden. The import is required to exposed the methods so that you can use them without the compiler warning you.

Comment: Yes, all my categories are in "compile sources". What confuses me is that you can't use the functions inside a category if you don't import it. But even if you don't import it, the function can be used if it collides.

Comment: Well, regarding "you can't use the functions" its matter of interpretation, try this `[yourInstance performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"yourCategoryMethod")]`. By the way by no means I suggest you do this, it just to test. This will work because the category is loaded and therefore the instance will respond to the selector from the category.